# Org capture to existing file

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, org-roam, org-protocol

I would like to use org-protocol to capture to an existing org file if one already exists. I am using a function to generate the file name interactively for the org file to be captured to:

```
(defun my/generate-org-note-name ()
  (setq my-org-note--name (read-string "Name: "))
  (setq my-org-note--time (format-time-string "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
  (expand-file-name (format "%s-%s.org" my-org-note--time my-org-note--name) (concat org-directory "links/")))
```

So is there a way to make Emacs search for some property like "URL" in my org directory and if it finds one, it appends the capture to it otherwise if it doesn't exist it creates a new file? As it stands now, if I use the [org-capture-extension](https://github.com/sprig/org-capture-extension), it runs the function to ask me for a file name and creates a new file.

My relevant capture templates are as follows:

```
("p" "Protocol" plain (file my/generate-org-note-name)
         "#+BEGIN_QUOTE\n%i\n#+END_QUOTE\n\n\n%?")
("L" "Protocol Link" plain (file my/generate-org-note-name)
         "%(format \"#+title: %s\n#+date: %U\n\" my-org-note--name my-org-note--time)#+author: %^{Author}\n#+filetags: :Web_Link:%^{Tags}\nLink: [[%:link][%(transform-square-brackets-to-round-ones \"%:description\")]]\n\n* %?\n")
```

## Edit

I realise that org-roam-protocol exists. Since I use org-roam I'm also open to any suggestions that use org-roam as well

Comment: What does this have to do with `org-protocol`? This seems to concern `org-capture` only.

Comment: The templates are the ones that I use with the org capture extension which uses org-protocol

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://github.com/sprig/org-capture-extension)?

Comment: yes, that is what I am talking about

Comment: IIUC you are trying to make your interactive file selection non-interactive  when you find some property in an unspecified place, presumably because it's a pain to select something in the browser to save and then have to go to Emacs to specify *where* it is going to be saved. So why have the interacitve function at all and not save to a fixed file?